# Join multiple files in a directory column wise

Tags: text-processing, columns

I would like to join about 100 files in the same directory column-wise. I have tried

```
  paste file1 file2 | column -s $'\t' -t
```

This works fine for 2 files. But when I try to do it for 100 files, I get an error saying

```
 column: line too long
```

Could someone please help where I am going wrong?

Comment: Can you use `column -c[num]` instead of using `-t` and `paste`? Or some combination thereof?

Comment: @mikeserv: Thank you. Could you please let me  know if there are unequal number of rows, how does paste function work here?

Comment: I don't know - I don't have your files.

Comment: @mikeserv: I am asking in general how does the paste function work for unequal number of rows

Comment: You know, that could make a very good question on its own - why not ask it? Hope @StephaneChazelas sees it. Here's a hopeful nudge for my part. Sorry I couldn't be of more help here.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have any errors. It's the limit of input line length, in bytes, define by `column`.

```
#define MAXLINELEN  (LINE_MAX + 1)
```

`LINE_MAX` is defined in `posix2_lim.h`, part of `GNU C library`:

```
/* The maximum length, in bytes, of an input line.  */                          
#define _POSIX2_LINE_MAX        2048
.....
#ifndef LINE_MAX                                                                
#define LINE_MAX        _POSIX2_LINE_MAX
```

**Note**

- [posix2_lim.h](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MHX/Convert-Binary-C-0.76/tests/include/include/bits/posix2_lim.h)
- [column.c](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux/+/v2.24-rc2/text-utils/column.c)

Comment: Thanks @Gnouc. How do I now go about doing the required task? I am new to unix. Please help

Comment: @biobudhan: You can recompile `column` with no limits `MAXLINELEN` but I think it not a good point.